# Viber Wingpanel icon broken

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

I'm getting error in viber icon which is as shown.

Can anyone give me solution to this problem?

[image: viber broken icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also changing the /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop file to be like the one here:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /opt/viber/Viber
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
Path=
```

Got it from [this](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus/issues/399#issuecomment-238048358) (which applies to the elementaryPlus icon set, but it should work with the stock elementary icon theme as well).

This is what I did to make the Viber icons show up.

Comment: Thank You very very much.
The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your environment following parameters:
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""

you can put it into your .profile file

Comment: i did append 

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""

to my ~/.profile file....

It isn't working.